# How to find out if an IP address belong to a network with python2?

Tags: python-2.7, networking, network-programming

If we have a IP address like 192.168.1.168. And We have a network represented by 192.168.1.0/24

Is there a good way (least code) to find out if the ip belong to the network?

The model netaddr seems can, but did not figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import netaddr

ip = netaddr.IPAddress('192.168.1.168')
network = netaddr.IPNetwork('192.168.1.0/24')

print ip in network
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
import socket
import struct

def in_net(ip, net):
    ipaddr = socket.inet_aton(ip)
    netaddr, netmask = net.split('/')
    netaddr = socket.inet_aton(netaddr)

    ipint = struct.unpack("!I", ipaddr)[0]
    netint = struct.unpack("!I", netaddr)[0]
    maskint = (0xFFFFFFFF << (32 - int(netmask))) & 0xFFFFFFFF

    return ipint & maskint == netint
```

Much easier in Python 3.3+:

```
import ipaddress

def in_net(ip, net):
    return ipaddress.ip_address(ip) in ipaddress.ip_network(net)
```

Comment: thanks. But do you think my answer can also fit the need?

Comment: @KramerLi: If the OP is willing and able to install the `netaddr` package, quite possibly.  But it's not part of Python so it may not be available on their systems.